# How to use bootstrap Modal with link_to in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I had asked this earlier but unfortunately I am still stuck. I have a link_to like this

```
<%= link_to "Click Here", page_path,, :id => 'login', "data-toggle" => "modal" %>
```

in page.html.erb (the page which I want to load in modal when the link gets clicked),I have

```
<div class="modal" id="loginModal">
    Test Content
</div>
```

in assets/page.js.coffee

```
$('#loginModal').modal(options)
```

but still, the link is not opening in a modal Any help ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add `data-target`

```
<%= link_to "Click Here", page_path, :id => 'login', "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => '#loginModal' %>
```

Comment: HI, the content is not on the same page. this link_to is on /page/ and I want to open /page/1 in bootstrap modal

Comment: Thanks, I did this though still the link is not working (I am clicking but it don't go anywhere). In my assets/javascript/page.js.coffee, I have put $('#loginModal').modal(options), is this fine ?

Comment: is ``options`` a object ? Do you have any javascript errors ?

Comment: And btw, are you sure this file is processed ? Try adding an alert

Comment: sorry, Options is no object, I just copied the code from another SO thread, I have removed it now. Though the code is still not working. I added alert() and it did worked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25492/discussion-between-icyborg-and-intrepidd)

Comment: You need to remove "data-toggle" => "modal" to make it work

Answer (score 11):

There is a prettier way to add `data` attributes in Rails. You can do something like this to get the same results.

```
<%= link_to 'Click Here', "#", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#modal"} %>
```

Comment: How do you load only the partial into the modal instead of the full page? For example, I only want the edit view.

Answer (score 1):

Using Rails 7 with **Bootstrap 5**

```
 <%= link_to 'Add user', '#',  {:remote => true, 'data-bs-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-bs-target' => '#exampleModal', class: 'nav-link'}  %>
```