# Rails - link_to_modal not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

I'm pretty new to Rails and I'm having a little trouble. I'm attempting to use jquery-modal-rails to present modal views in my app. I've followed the directions [here on GitHub](https://github.com/dei79/jquery-modal-rails) PERFECTLY, and I've done it several times, but for some reason I keep getting this error:

> undefined method `link_to_modal'

Specifying this line:

```
<%= user.first_name + " " + user.last_name %>
```

Can someone PLEASE help!

I'm using version 4.0.3 of Rails. If you need any more info, just let me know.

Comment: Did you run `bundle` after adding the gem to your Gemfile? Did you restart your app?

Comment: Yes I've ran bundle install and restarted the server several time to no avail.

Comment: It's not the problem with this line. But I think, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188850/how-to-use-bootstrap-modal-with-link-to-in-rails) might help you very much.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user3383458 but in this question they are using Bootstrap, I'm trying to avoid using something so hefty, as I'm only trying to present a window modally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong! I was using a stylesheet partial that wasn't loading my

> application.js

and my

> application.css

After I got rid of the partial and put that code back in my

> application.html.erb

everything is working perfectly(using Fancybox).